# I got this error in my docker with laravel : Connection refused Connection to mysql in migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

## When I run docker-compose artisan migrate or ./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate,

## I get this error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = warehouse and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

[You can see the Error here (Connection refused)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmmvg.png)

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=warehouse
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
```

docker-compose.yml
You can see [docker-compose file, the MySQL part] here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtkRW.png)

This is a project from scratch and everything is default with the sail.
I can connect to MySQL as well.
Everything is running

You can see docker ps details: [Everything is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRjOf.png)

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - mailpit
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - redis-cli
                - ping
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        environment:
            MEILI_NO_ANALYTICS: '${MEILISEARCH_NO_ANALYTICS:-false}'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-meilisearch:/meili_data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - wget
                - '--no-verbose'
                - '--spider'
                - 'http://localhost:7700/health'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailpit:
        image: 'axllent/mailpit:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-meilisearch:
        driver: local
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `docker ps` and checkout ports of your MySQL container. if it is like `0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp` then your database should be accessible on 3306 if it
`0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp` then your database should be accessible on 3307.
Also, try to run `sail mysql` if that is not working then your database container is not running properly.
I just check output of your `docker ps` - You need to use `DB_PORT=3307` in your env to connect to database.

Answer (score -1):

Confirm that your Laravel application and the MySQL database are on the same Docker network. By default, containers in the same Docker Compose file share a network. Check your docker-compose.yml file for network settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I added the whole docker file.
It's a default file, when I create a Laravel project with Sail.
I think it's in the same network.